# Is it possible for an initialized pointer to be NULL in during the run time of code?

Tags: c, pointers, memory, null

As robustness and best practices, If a pointer to any data type will be accessed, we should protect it against being NULL before accessing...

for example:

```
    int Var;
    int *ptrToVar = &Var;

    int main(void)
    {
       if (ptrToVar != NULL)
       {
         (*ptrToVar) = 6;
       }
       else
       {
         //do nothing
       }
    }
```

My question is:

Is it possible for `ptrToVar` to be `NULL` during the run time of code?

If yes! So What can make the pointer `ptrToVar` be `NULL` during run time?!

Comment: For the simple program that you posted, it won't. For large programs there are, all kinds of bugs show up.

Comment: If you assign `NULL` to a pointer, it will of course be `NULL`. Also, uninitialized global variables and local static variables will be zero initialized which means they will be `NULL`. Also, debuggers will initialize all data to zero (i.e. `NULL` for pointers) which may be hiding bugs with you accessing uninitialized pointers.

Comment: Given that there are no function calls in the code, there's nothing here that modifies `ptrToVar`.  However, if you called code in other files, because `ptrToVar` is a global variable, you'd have to look at the other code to see if it references `ptrToVar`.  Even more insidiously, the chances are that either `*(&Var-1) = 0;` or `*(&Var+1) = 0;` (both of which invoke undefined behaviour) will mangle the pointer, so you have to worry with global variables about which code modifies them.  Just one more reason to avoid global variables whenever possible.

Comment: If any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark next to it. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Answer (score 1):

It can only be NULL if your program has undefined behavior. In a correct C program a local variable will never be NULL. Therefore the check is not needed.

> 6.3.2.3 Pointers
>
> p2: An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type
> void *, is called a null pointer constant. *If a null pointer constant is converted to a
> pointer type, the resulting pointer, called a null pointer, is guaranteed to compare unequal
> to a pointer to any object or function.*

If your program has bugs, use assert() to locate them, it will print a warning and abort immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Global variables are stored in the data-segment. If the global variables are not initialized they will be intiialized to 0 . So it is just the initialization which will be to 0. You have a pointer `ptrToVar` pointing to this variable. So this pointer can never be NULL unless there is some unallocated memory access or UB in your code.

You can try and print the address the pointer is pointing to it can't be NULL.(In a defined behavior).

If we just consider the code which you have posted the pointer `ptrToVar` is not NULL.

Answer (score 0):

In your code `int *ptrToVar = &Var` ptrTovar is having the address of var.
Hence it has the address of the var, the ptrTovar will not be NULL.
if the ptrTovar is a global variable or if you have initialized the ptrTovar as NULL, then the address will be NULL.
if you print `printf("address:%d\n",ptrTovar)`, it will print some address, so it not NULL in your code.